# How to use aws elastic-search in Zeebe operate

Tags: aws-elasticsearch, zeebe

I have deployed zeebe cluster and zeebe operate separately, In the zeebe cluster, the elasticsearch is configured with the AWS ELK but facing issue with zeebe operate.

Configmap.yaml:

```
kind: ConfigMapmetadata:
name: {{ include "zeebe-operate.fullname" . }}
apiVersion: v1
data:
application.yml: |
# Operate configuration file
camunda.operate:
elasticsearch:
host: {{ .Values.global.elasticsearch.host }}
port: {{ .Values.global.elasticsearch.port }}
username: {{ .Values.global.elasticsearch.username }}
password: {{ .Values.global.elasticsearch.password }}
prefix: zeebe-record-operate
```

ERROR:

```
2020-06-29 05:35:10.397 ERROR 6 --- [ main] o.c.o.e.ElasticsearchConnector : Error occurred while connecting to Elasticsearch: clustername [elasticsearch], https://xx.xx.xx.x.x.x.x.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443. Will be retried...

java.io.IOException: https://xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx-x..ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:964) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-6.8.7.jar!/:6.8.7]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:233) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-6.8.7.jar!/:6.8.7]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1764) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.8.jar!/:6.8.7]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1734) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.8.jar!/:6.8.7]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1696) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.8.jar!/:6.8.7]
at org.elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.health(ClusterClient.java:146) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.8.8.jar!/:6.8.7]
at org.camunda.operate.es.ElasticsearchConnector.checkHealth(ElasticsearchConnector.java:89) ~[camunda-operate-common-0.23.0.jar!/:?]
at org.camunda.operate.es.ElasticsearchConnector.createEsClient(ElasticsearchConnector.java:75) ~[camunda-operate-common-0.23.0.jar!/:?]
at org.camunda.operate.es.ElasticsearchConnector.esClient(ElasticsearchConnector.java:51) ~[camunda-operate-common-0.23.0.jar!/:?]
at org.camunda.operate.es.ElasticsearchConnector$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$670b527.CGLIB$esClient$0() ~[camunda-operate-common-0.23.0.jar!/:?]
at org.camunda.operate.es.ElasticsearchConnector$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$670b527$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$af2d84c1.invoke() ~[camunda-operate-common-0.23.0.jar!/:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.camunda.operate.es.ElasticsearchConnector$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$670b527.esClient() ~[camunda-o
URL is accessible for zeebe cluster but for zeebe operate it is not working as you can see the logs of zeebe broker
```

Logs of Broker:

```
2020-06-23 08:23:29.759 [] [main] DEBUG io.zeebe.broker.system - Bootstrap Broker-0 [7/10]: topology manager started in 1 ms
2020-06-23 08:23:29.761 [] [main] INFO io.zeebe.broker.system - Bootstrap Broker-0 [8/10]: metric's server
2020-06-23 08:23:29.820 [] [main] DEBUG io.zeebe.broker.system - Bootstrap Broker-0 [8/10]: metric's server started in 58 ms
2020-06-23 08:23:29.821 [] [main] INFO io.zeebe.broker.system - Bootstrap Broker-0 [9/10]: leader management request handler
2020-06-23 08:23:29.826 [] [main] DEBUG io.zeebe.broker.system - Bootstrap Broker-0 [9/10]: leader management request handler started in 2 ms
2020-06-23 08:23:29.826 [] [main] INFO io.zeebe.broker.system - Bootstrap Broker-0 [10/10]: zeebe partitions
2020-06-23 08:23:29.832 [] [main] INFO io.zeebe.broker.system - Bootstrap Broker-0 partitions [1/1]: partition 1
2020-06-23 08:23:30.231 [] [main] DEBUG io.zeebe.broker.exporter - Exporter configured with ElasticsearchExporterConfiguration{url='https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.xx.xx.xx.x.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443', index=IndexConfiguration{indexPrefix='zeebe-record', createTemplate=true, command=false, event=true, rejection=false, error=true, deployment=true, incident=true, job=true, message=false, messageSubscription=false, variable=true, variableDocument=true, workflowInstance=true, workflowInstanceCreation=false, workflowInstanceSubscription=false, ignoreVariablesAbove=8191}, bulk=BulkConfiguration{delay=5, size=1000}, authentication=AuthenticationConfiguration{username='kibana'}}
2020-06-23 08:23:30.236 [Broker-0-ZeebePartition-1] [Broker-0-zb-actors-1] DEBUG io.zeebe.broker.system - Removing follower partition service for partition PartitionId{id=1, group=raft-partition}
2020-06-23 08:23:30.325 [Broker-0-ZeebePartition-1] [Broker-0-zb-actors-1] DEBUG io.zeebe.broker.system - Partition role transitioning from null to LEADER
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: it's trying to connect on : `https://host-url:443` as per log can you update the value and add elasticsearch URL with port if 9200 applicable.

Comment: if you are using helm you can update value here : https://github.com/zeebe-io/zeebe-operate-helm/blob/master/zeebe-operate/values.yaml